# Use CSS to remove <br> in part of Div_class block

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to remove the 2nd, 3rd and 4th `<br>` in this code with CSS.

`<div class="product-attributes"><span class="pa_brand"> Woolhalla Yarn</span><br><span class="pa_fibers"> 70WS 30SE</span><br><span class="pa_meterage"> 300</span><br><span class="pa_nm"> 1/3</span></div>`

I tried `.product-attributes br {display: none;}` but it removes all of them. I can't seem to let the first one stay and remove the 2nd, 3rd and 4th one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```css
.product-attributes br:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

or

```css
.product-attributes br:nth-of-type(1n+2) {
  display: none;
}
```

See:

- [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)
- [`not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)
- [`first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)

Comment: @Amir Saadallah Can you clarify why it wouldn't work?

Comment: @AmirSaadallah Got it now – fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```css
 .product-attributes br:not(:first-of-type){
       display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="product-attributes"><span class="pa_brand"> Woolhalla Yarn</span><br><span class="pa_fibers"> 70WS 30SE</span><br><span class="pa_meterage"> 300</span><br><span class="pa_nm"> 1/3</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way - the second rule overwrites the first rule for the first `br`:

```css
div.product-attributes > br {
  display: none;
}
div.product-attributes > br:first-of-type {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-attributes">
  <span class="pa_brand"> Woolhalla Yarn</span>
  <br>
  <span class="pa_fibers"> 70WS 30SE</span>
  <br>
  <span class="pa_meterage"> 300</span>
  <br>
  <span class="pa_nm"> 1/3</span>
</div>
```